# qgis - create layer - can't see the lat lon values

Tags: qgis

I'm using qgis 3 and generate a lot of layers types, but in any case I don't find the lat lon values of the points.
 I have tried to use the attributes table calculator (added fields $x and $y but it showed me big value, I guess in meters and not the lat lon).

- I want to see the lat-lon without using the plugin of lat-lon tools.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a virtual field using field calculator of your layer and complete for longitude

```
 x(transform($geometry,  layer_property( 'CHEF_LIEU20160610124929878', 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326'))
```

and for latitude

```
y(transform($geometry,  layer_property( 'CHEF_LIEU20160610124929878', 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326'))
```

where 'CHEF_LIEU20160610124929878' is your layer identifier

You will see a full demo to demonstrate the way to do it

[image: QGIS x, y to lon, lat]

Comment: I think you probably meant `y(transform...` for the latitude line.

Comment: I am finding that when I specify `EPSG: 4326` (WGS 84) vs `EPSG:4269` (NAD83) I get the same results even down to the 12th decimal point, whereas they should differ more about the 6th decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

In **QGIS 3.8** (June 2019), there is now an algorithm to add the X and Y values. It can reproject coordinates on the fly.

[image]

If you still need a Degree Minute or Degree Minute Second format, you need to use first the `to_dm` or `to_dms` expression to add these fields into the attribute table.